# iOS UIImage alpha not being detected properly

Tags: ios

The code below loops through the pixels of an image and gets the alpha value of each pixel. If the alpha is zero, it creates a red dot at the x,y coordinate. The following are 2 images with transparent backgrounds. The first is an image of the letter "C" and there is distortion as the red dots are drawn. The second is an image of the letter "D" and it works perfectly fine, with red dots being placed exactly where alpha equals zero. Does anyone have any idea why the alpha of one image is being detected in a distorted pattern while another image is being detected perfectly fine? I have really been struggling to figure this out. It makes no sense to me. Thanks in advance for any advice!!!

C has problems -->
http://i45.tinypic.com/rtdyet.png

D works perfectly fine -->
http://i45.tinypic.com/21mb3om.png

```
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
UInt8 *pixels = (UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

for (int x = 0; x < size.width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < size.height; y++)
    {
        int index = ((x + (y * (int)size.width)) * 4) + 3;
        CGFloat alpha = pixels[index];
        if (alpha == 0)
        {
            CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), x, y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), x, y);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        }
    }
}

UIImage *test = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:test];
testView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

Comment: Your code is assuming 32-bit RGBA pixels. Are you sure that is true for every image?

Comment: All my images are created within the app in the same exact manner. The only difference is the letter that is drawn in the image. Some images work (D, J, O, E) but most others are distorted.

Comment: Where is the size variable coming from? Is it from image.size?

Comment: Yes, the new image I am creating is the same size as the one I am scanning the pixels. When I first started testing I didn't know that some letters worked so I figured I had a width property not set correctly, but once I found that other images with different letters work fine, I sort of dismissed the idea that there might be a problem with the size. But now that you mention it, it still looks suspiciously like the width isn't being set correctly. I will look into it again.

Comment: The data length doesn't seem to add up properly. If I have an image size 66x236, I would expect CFDataGetLength(data) to return 66x236x4 = 62304, however it returns 67968. I think this is where my problem is but it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: 67968 is equal to 72x236x4. The skewed image you posted looks like it's about 6 pixels off on each line. Are you assuming 66x236 or are you really checking image.size?

Comment: I just stepped through the code with 3 different images (I,C,D) and got the exact image size, data length, and *expected* data length of each:

Comment: I -> 66x236 -> 62304 -> 67968   C -> 126x236 -> 118944 -> 120832   D -> 128x236 -> 120832 -> 120832    Of these 3, the D image was the only length that produced the expected length (and displayed properly)  I really think there is a bug with CFDataGetLength.

Comment: OK, I figured out this has to be a bug. I was creating a UIImage using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() and this didn't work, however if I write the same image to a file, like this:    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()) writeToFile:path atomically:YES] and use imageWithContentsOfFile, then it works every time. Thanks for the help rmaddy, you pushed me in the right direction, how can I give you credit for your help?

Comment: Although I did get this to work consistently by writing the images to a file, if anyone knows another way to get the pixel data from an image that will work consistently without writing to a file, I would really appreciate it. It is a lot of extra work for nothing.